# How transition from keras fit_generator() to the models input layer works exactly

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am working with image data and some scalar meta-data (like hair-color, eye-color, ...).
I am using a self-written generator to use the Keras `.fit_generator()` function.

The process looks like the following:

After applying some data augmentation I have the shape `((10,200,200,3),(10,),(10,),(10,),(10,))` of my dataset (For imagination: I extract images of shape `(200,200,3`) and stack together 10 of them -> `(10,200,200,3)`. Accordingly, I duplicate the metadata 10 times -> shapes `(10,)` for each )

Afterwards I use the tensorflow function `dataset = dataset.apply(tf.contrib.data.unbatch())` so that the shape of my dataset is `((200,200,3),(),(),(),())`. From here I now share the code with you:

**Edit (more Code):**

Following code are the last line of my generator-function which will be called from the `.fit_generator()` function in the `main()`

```
shape_dataset = tf.shape(dataset) # shape ((10,200,200,3),(10,),(10,),(10,),(10,)) like I mentioned above
dataset = dataset.apply(tf.contrib.data.unbatch()) # shape ((200,200,3),(),(),(),()) like I mentioned a bove 
dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size = buffer_size)
dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size=batch_size) 
dataset = dataset.repeat()
iterator_all = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
next_all = iterator_all.get_next()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    while True:
        try:
            image, eye_color, hair_ color, labels = sess.run(next_all)
            yield [image, eye_color, hair_ color], labels

        except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
            print('Finished')
            break
```

This tensor will now be fed into my network via the keras `.fit_generator()` function.
The input layer looks like the following:

```
input_image = Input(shape=(200, 200, 3))
input_eye_color = Input(shape=(1,), name='input_ec')
input_hair_color = Input(shape=(1,), name='input_hc')
```

Now I have some question:

1. Where does the 10 from `((10,200,200,3),(10,),(10,),(10,),(10,))` go through the `tf.contrib.data.unbatch())` function? For me it feels like I am losing these 10 values and just get 1?
2. The `fit_generator()` function works batch-wise, but how? Stupid as i sounds I have the feeling my network gets data of shape `((200,200,3),(),(),(),())` for one iteration step. Obviously it gets data like  `((8,10,200,200,3),(8,10,),(8,10,),(8, 10,),(8, 10,))` as batch size is 8.

Can someone explain this issue with the shapes to me?
And really I read a lot but I still do not get it.

Thanks for your help :-)

Answer (score 0):

For the model you described here

```
input_image = Input(shape=(200, 200, 3), name='input_img')
input_eye_color = Input(shape=(1,), name='input_ec')
input_hair_color = Input(shape=(1,), name='input_hc')
```

In keras, the `fit_generator` accepts one of the following two inputs:

1. List of tensors `[bsize x 200 x 200 x 3, bsize x 1, bsize x 1]`
2. Dictionary of tensors

   { 'input_img' : `bsize x 200 x 200 x3`,
      'input_ec': `bsize x 1`, 
      'input_hc': `bsize x 1` }

As you see, this is quite different from what you actually provided.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I edited my question with a bit more code (see part below "Edit(more code):). Can you maybe just help m with the shapes/ dimensions - I'd be very thankful.